# ifelse function in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am using the formula below to calculate a vector
but when executed, it returns a matrix; here is the code:

```
FdeValue <- ifelse(fde.4$ResourceId == 2196 |fde.4$FullYearForecast == 'Yes' | !is.na(fde.2$8), 0, fde.4$Value)
```

Any idea why will it do that ?

Comment: Can you post data for `fde.4` ?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible! Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: unfortunately , i cant upload the data. Problem i see is that the heading/column name of the resulting vector is the column name used in the third condition, which is really weird

Comment: At least show us the `str` of the data then. Also, a non-standard column name (here, `8`) shouldn't be able to be used with the `$` operator; is this code actually running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it is because of the dim of your logical input. Ifelse returns a value of the same dim as your logical input.
Try this:

```
c(fde.4$ResourceId ,fde.4$FullYearForecast, is.na(fde.2$8))==c(2196,'Yes', FALSE)
```

Comment: Try this:  c(fde.4$ResourceId ,fde.4$FullYearForecast, is.na(fde.2$8))==c(2196,'Yes', FALSE)

Comment: awesome, it worked, but i still do not understand why it happened , i am using same formula for another vector and that is working fine, why would ifelse return the same dimension as logical input ?

Comment: Ifelse checks every single element of your logical vector and do not see it as an unique assumption. Therefore for every 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' it returns the output you indicate.

Comment: It is applied element by element so if you apply an operation on a vector of length n or a matrix of dim n*m you get an output of respectively length n or dim n*m